# Embedding a widget to a page

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that our users will use to embed a widget on their page:

```
var ttp_number = "1Z123489754897";
var ttp_key = "1234567890123457890123";
var ttp_width = 850;
var ttp_height = 650;
var ttp_m_width = 260;
var ttp_m_height = 200;

(function(){
    document.write('<div id="ttp"></div>');
    s=document.createElement('script');
    s.type="text/javascript";
    s.src="//example.com/embed.js";
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('ttp').appendChild(s);",1);
})();
```

Is there a way to reorganize or make this more compact (other than minifying)?

Right now the big list of variables feels inefficient just declaring them one at a time, but I'm not sure what the alternate would be.

NOTE: I need to keep the script as compact as possible as the people who are copy/pasting this code many times know very little (if any) javascript, so if they some massive block of code, they'll freak out or stand a bigger chance of screwing it up.

Comment: What is the purpose of the setTimeout?

Comment: Honestly, not sure. Saw it in use somewhere a while back with a script used to asynchronously load a script.

Answer (score 2):

- **Don't make your code more compact, it's a futile exercise. Use a minifier or even a compiler/optimizer. Your source code should be as readable as possible**
- `document.write` is evil, don't use it.

Here's how I would write it:

```
var tpp = {
    number: "1Z123489754897",
    key: "1234567890123457890123",
    width: 850,
    height: 200,
    "m width": 260,
    "m height": 200
};

function init(settings) {
    var div, script;
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "ttp";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "//example.com/embed.js";
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.attachEvent("load", function() {
    init(tpp);
});
/* or */
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    init(tpp);
});
```

- Adding the event listener on `window.load` avoids having to do the setTimeout later on.
- Also, when doing a setTimeout, don't use the `eval` variant, use an anonymous function:

---

```
setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('ttp').appendChild(s);
}, 1);
```

Comment: This is a snippet of code someone would copy/paste from our app and into their site. Giving them a huge block of code will likely freak them the heck out (many of these people know very little javascript...just basic HTML/CSS)

Comment: @Shpigford they shouldn't freak out because of huge blocks of code as long as they are understandable.

Comment: These are people that don't know _any_ javascript. They won't understand it regardless of how readable it is. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest version I could think of, without resorting to some code golf:

```
// Use an array instead of separate variables
// You could extract it into variables in your script if you need to
var __ttp = [ "1Z123", "1234", 850, 650, 260, 200 ];

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = '//example.com/embed.js';

// Unless you need to create a separate div, you can append the script tag to the body
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Removing the comments and blank lines would make it into just 5 lines of code.

If you need a separate div, you could replace the last line with this one:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'ttp';
document.body.appendChild(div).appendChild(script);
```

Disclaimer: I have no idea whether you might need to use `setTimeout` to run the code above.